# What is $Pr(X>0,X+Y<0)$ given that $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d. standard normal?

Tags: probability, solution-verification, normal-distribution

> Suppose that $X,Y \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Determine the probability $Pr(X>0,X+Y<0)$.

First, I tried to visualize $X>0$ as follows (where the horizontal axis represents $X$ and the vertical axis represents $Y$):

[image]

Also, I tried to visualize $X+Y<0$ like this:

[image]

Now, since the joint PDF of $X$ and $Y$ is radially symmetric, I think that $Pr(X>0,X+Y<0) = \frac18$.
Is my thinking correct?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Yes your thinking is correct.

Comment: @MathLover Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A verification using manual integration!

$$Pr(X>0,X+Y<0)=\int_0^\infty\int_{-\infty}^{-x}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-y^2/2}\,dy\,dx$$

$$=\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}\bigg[\int_{-\infty}^{-x}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-y^2/2}\,dy\bigg]\,dx=-\int_{1/2}^0\,u\,du=\frac{1}{8}$$

Where, $$u=\int_{-\infty}^{-x}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-y^2/2}\,dy=\Phi(-x)$$
hence, by leibnitz's integral rule
$$\Rightarrow du=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}\cdot(-\,dx)$$

and $(x=0)\Rightarrow (u=\frac{1}{2})$ and $(x=\infty)\Rightarrow (u=0)$

Comment: If you decide to downvote, please explain why you did so too.